# How do you solve a timeout error in a python dropbox upload script?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, dropbox

I'm currently working on a project to do a timelapse with a raspberry pi3 (which works well, capturing the photos ain't a problem).

However, I used another script to upload those photos to a dropbox account and it work all well, until I checked it out today, seeing a timeout error.

Does anyone know how this could solved?

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 453, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1426, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1149, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise WantReadError()
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 344, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 456, in wrap_socket
    raise timeout('select timed out')
socket.timeout: select timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 306, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value)
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='content.dropboxapi.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/time/picture/drop.py", line 16, in <module>
    response = db.files_upload(f.read(), dname)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dropbox/base.py", line 2293, in files_upload
    f,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 274, in request
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 365, in request_json_string_with_retry
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 449, in request_json_string
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 581, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='content.dropboxapi.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)
>>>
```

This is how the code to upload on dropbox looks:

```
import dropbox
from time import sleep


db = dropbox.Dropbox('apikeyplaceholder')


for i in range(4500): ##4500

    name = 'image{0:04d}.jpg'

    fname = '/home/pi/Desktop/time/picture/'+name.format(i)
    dname = '/'+name.format(i)

    f = open(fname, 'rb')
    response = db.files_upload(f.read(), dname)
    print ('uploaded:', response)

    sleep(585)

f.close()
```

---

**NEW ERROR:**

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 317, in _send_until_done
    return self.connection.send(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1256, in send
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1151, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise WantWriteError()
OpenSSL.SSL.WantWriteError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 936, in _send_output
    self.send(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 908, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 328, in sendall
    sent = self._send_until_done(data[total_sent:total_sent + SSL_WRITE_BLOCKSIZE])
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 320, in _send_until_done
    raise timeout()
socket.timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 936, in _send_output
    self.send(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 908, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 328, in sendall
    sent = self._send_until_done(data[total_sent:total_sent + SSL_WRITE_BLOCKSIZE])
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 320, in _send_until_done
    raise timeout()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', timeout())

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/time/bild/drop.py", line 20, in <module>
    response = upload(f, dname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/backoff/_sync.py", line 94, in retry
    ret = target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/time/bild/drop.py", line 11, in upload
    return db.files_upload(f.read(), dname)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dropbox/base.py", line 2293, in files_upload
    f,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 274, in request
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 365, in request_json_string_with_retry
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 449, in request_json_string
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 581, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', timeout())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you implement code to handle the timeout you first need to think about how you want to handle it. A common strategy is the following:

- Try re-uploading a certain number of times, potentially coupled with [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) (e.g. using [this library](https://github.com/litl/backoff))
- If that fails either skip the current image or abort the process completely.

Depending on your setup, you might want to put the uploading code into a separate thread so that delays during uploads don't interfere with capturing the photos.

A simple example using the `backoff` library I've linked to above (untested):

```
from time import sleep

import backoff
import dropbox
import requests

db = dropbox.Dropbox('apikeyplaceholder')

@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout)
def upload(f, name):
    return db.files_upload(f.read(), dname)

NAME_PATTERN = '/image{0:04d}.jpg'
for i in range(4500):
    name = NAME_PATTERN.format(i)
    fname = '/home/pi/Desktop/time/picture' + name
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        response = upload(f, name)
    print ('uploaded:', response)
    sleep(585)
```

Comment: They're in separate files already so they don't interfere. Couldn't something like try / except timeout work here? I just can't figure out how.

Comment: I've added a simple example.

Comment: Thank you. The script itself works. I'll let it run until tomorrow and see if I receive any error. I'll let you know here tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately, the script gave an error after like 3-4 hours, stopping the upload. I've added it to the post above.

Comment: You can handle the new error with the same approach. Please refer to the documentation of the `backoff` library for details on configuring which exceptions are handled how.

Comment: I've added: "@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError)", how this will do it.

Comment: Btw, do you have idea how I could reduce the file that is uploaded? E.g. original capture image has 1,3 MB, but on dropbox it should have like 0,2 MB if possible (low quality). Why? Dropbox is mainly important for me to know if the timelapse is still running.

Comment: Reducing the image file size is a separate question. Please research possible approaches (e.g. google "python reduce image file size") and, if you don't find what you need, post a separate question.